# Database error when running Android app with SQLite database

Tags: android, sqlite, android-emulator

**Specific error:** An Android app with an SQLite database fails when attempting to access data/data/package/databases

*Note: I am aware that many articles have been posted on Stackoverflow as well as a number of recommended sites concerning how to copy the sqlite file from the Assets folder into the data/data/package/databases folder. However, my implementation only works on the emulator and not real devices. I think I am missing a piece of the puzzle.*

**My Question**
Can anyone identify point of failure in my code? I truly think this is one of those matters where a fresh pair of eyes will quickly find the error. Thank you in advance for any insight you can provide...

**Error Logs (BOLD ITEMS ARE THE FAILURE POINTS):**
11-02 20:22:17.045: INFO/Process(15318): Sending signal. PID: 15318 SIG: 9
**11-02 20:22:17.055: INFO/ActivityManager(2697): Process com.game.myapp (pid 15318) has died.
11-02 20:22:17.055: INFO/WindowManager(2697): WIN DEATH: Window{40922a70 com.game.myapp/com.game.myapp.MainActivity paused=true}**

**My code**

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "ttg.db";
public static String DATABASE_PATH = "/data/data/com.game.myapp/databases/";

private SQLiteDatabase ttgDatabase;
private Context myContext = null;

DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    this.myContext = context;
}



    public void createDataBase() throws IOException{
            boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();
                if(dbExist){
       //do nothing
            }else{

        this.getReadableDatabase();

            try {
                copyDataBase();

                    } catch (IOException e) {
                  throw new Error("Error copying database");
                }   
            }
          }


                 private boolean checkDataBase(){
                        SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

                        try{
                    String myPath = DATABASE_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
                checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,         SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

        }catch(SQLiteException e){

        } 

        if(checkDB != null){
            checkDB.close();
        }

                return checkDB != null ? true : false;
      }


            private void copyDataBase() throws IOException{
                    File fileTest = myContext.getFileStreamPath(DATABASE_NAME);
                            boolean exists = fileTest.exists();
                    if (!exists) {

            OutputStream databaseOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(DATABASE_PATH + DATABASE_NAME);
            InputStream databaseInputStream;

             databaseInputStream = myContext.getAssets().open(DATABASE_NAME);
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
             int length;
                while ((length = databaseInputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
               databaseOutputStream.write(buffer);
             }
                // Close the streams
               databaseInputStream.close();
               databaseOutputStream.flush();
                   databaseOutputStream.close();
                 }
               }

                public void openDataBase() throws SQLException{
                        //Open the database
                    String myPath = DATABASE_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
                    ttgDatabase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,  SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
                   } 

                      @Override
                public synchronized void close() {
                        if(ttgDatabase != null)
                            ttgDatabase.close();
                super.close();
        }


@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

}


@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

}
```

Comment: Holy crap what happened to your indenting?  I can't tell where anything is..

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! If you find a response is helpful, please up vote it. If the response successfully answers your question, please click the green check mark next to it to accept the answer. Also please look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask for advice on how to write a good question

Comment: Hmm, the logs that you posted only show that your app has died and not the cause of it. Perhaps you could post the lengthier version of the logs? 


Something along the lines of:
 
AndroidRuntime  E  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: you don't need to use the path (/data/data/com.game.myapp/databases) when using an SQLHelper, it will find the database path for your app for you, just need the filename.  Also, you're really not using the OpenHelper class correctly there... should check out the docs on that
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html
this is a good video too, watch lesson 3.3: databases
http://marakana.com/techtv/android_bootcamp_screencast_series.html#

Comment: Thanks for the great feedback. For some reason, I couldn't get this to work so I created the table programmatically.

Comment: I don't know why I got a badge for this answer, but then I looked at it again.  Still telling you, your code as written was guaranteed to fail because you would be corrupting your database files.  See answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here.  You probably have corrupt database files (actually, 1 out of 1024 that you DON'T)

```
while ((length = databaseInputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
    databaseOutputStream.write(buffer);
}
```

Need to specify the length of the buffer read when writing.  What you'll get is the whole 1024 bytes on each write.

I hate writing the "InputStream/OutputStream" copy code, and I see it all over the place.  If you want to use it, I created a slimmed down version of apache commons libraries.  Lots of stuff you'd never use, but some great util code in there:

http://www.touchlab.co/blog/android-mini-commons/

Otherwise, use this method instead of what you're using now:

[http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html#write(byte[], int, int)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html#write%28byte%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%29)

Comment: All of your blog links 404 now.